# Setting animator parameter on a single instance of a prefab sets the parameter for all instances

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

I have created a `Prefab` with the intention of creating many instances of the same `GameObject`.  However whilst I would like all of these instances to use the same `Animation`s and `Animation Controller`, I want to be able to control the state for each instance independantly.

My `Prefab` currently consists of a `Sprite Renderer`, `Script`, `Box Collider 2D` and `Animator`.  The `Animator` has an `Animation Controller` which has two states that are controlled using a boolean parameter.

The `Script` contains the following code:

```
private Animator _animator;
private bool _isAlive;

private void Start()
{
    _animator = gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();
}

void Update ()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        var hit = Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition), Vector2.zero);
        _isAlive = hit.collider == null;
    }

    _animator.SetBool("isAlive", _isAlive);
}
```

The `Animation`s are both created using sprite sheets.

So in my example I would like the `Animator` to only animate the `GameObject` that has been clicked.  The click detection part works fine but all instances of the `GameObject` animate when any `GameObject` is clicked.

Comment: Your problem is actually simpler than that. Because of the way you've structure your `Update` function, each instance of that script is going to run the same check every time the player clicks. You have multiple animators, but you're telling all of them to do the same thing. Revise your check; either pull it into another script that targets only one object, or have each object check if *it* was clicked.

Comment: When creating an instance of a prefab is the script not run in the context of that instance? For example assuming these game objects do not overlap I'd expect the above code to set all the objects that weren't clicked to `_isAlive=true` and the single one that was clicked to `_isAlive=false`.

Comment: Yes, sort of. Each instance is firing and evaluating its own raycast, but you're telling each of them to do the exact same thing. The simplest change you could make is to check if the raycast hit "my" collider or not (relative to the script instance).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [rutter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1251354/rutter) I have solved my issue by changing:

```
_isAlive = hit.collider == null;
```

to

```
_isAlive = hit.collider == gameObject.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
```

I had falsely assumed that the raycast was in the context of the gameObject rather than the whole scene.